# Architecture agnostic code

Tags: c, unsigned-integer, unsigned-long-long-int

I have this piece of code where the aim is to determine if the packet received is valid or not:

```
size_t offset_to_a, offset_to_b;
u_int32_t file_name_length;
u_int32_t packet_length;

if ((offset_to_a + offset_to_b + file_name_length) > packet_length) {
    // Invalid packet
}
```

`size_t` is `u_int64_t` perhaps because the cpu is a 64-bit one.

Now when `file_name_length` has a value `0xFFFFFFFF` (which is invalid), then the packet is deemed invalid.

But if `size_t` becomes `u_int32_t` because of the underlying architecture, then for the same value of `file_name_length`, the condition fails because the value would wrap around, and the packet is deemed valid.

How can I make this condition generic enough to work on both 32/64-bit architectures?

Thanks!

Comment: The value 0xFFFFFFFF is the maximum 32-bit unsigned integer — and doesn't make a 64-bit value break sweat.  As such, it would work identically if `size_t` is 32-bits.  Maybe you mistyped `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` for the 64-bit value.  Have you considered the fixed-size types from `<stdint.h>` and `<inttypes.h>`?  These are often used in modern code when the sizes are fixed. (There are multiple incompatible alternatives.) Technically, they're optional — some platform might not support `uint16_t` and in that case, there would be no type `uint16_t`.  There are always `uint_least16_t` types, though.

Comment: "*Now when file_name_length has a value 0xFFFFFFFF (which is invalid),*" So why then not just do a simple `if (file_name_length >= 0xffffffff) { // Invalid packet} `?

Comment: @alk: Your suggestion is valid and we incorporated it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to only use subtraction, and only subtract after verifying that the subtraction won't wrap. Something like this:

```
if (offset_to_a > packet_length || packet_length - offset_to_a < file_name_length) {
    // invalid packet
}
size_t remain = packet_length - offset_to_a;
if (offset_to_b > remain || remain - offset_to_b < file_name_length) {
    // invalid packet
}
```